# update the version of the google-services plugin or update com.google.android.gsm to 8.3.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

it gives me this error 
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0."
>   Here is my build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.uti.magic"
    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile files ('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar')
compile files ('libs/isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar')
}
buildscript {
dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
}
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
dependencies {
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'

// Required for OneSignal, even if you have added FCM.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'

// Required for geotagging
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"

// play-services-analytics is only needed when using 8.1.0 or older.
// compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the top of build.gradle of app module.